# Can you fail a Javascript Promise from its success handler?

Tags: javascript, promise

I doubt this is a feature of JS Promises, but I have a Promise that can resolve nicely, but still contain erroneous data (ie, a null value in an unfortunate spot). I want the erroneous data to be passed through the same Promises fail function instead, if that null value is there.

I'm wondering if there is a way to fail a promise from its own success handler?

Comment: Just throw an error, and it'll proceed to the following `.catch`?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "success" handler. Within `Promise` constructor you can perform logic and call `reject` argument of executor function. Can you include the code that you are referencing and the expected result at at the question?

Comment: Having a `.catch` beneath the `.then` will catch any error in the Promise as well as any error inside the above `.then`.

Comment: @CataJohn `.catch()` will not necessarily catch "any error in the Promise" `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(1);
  throw new Error(2);
})
.then(resolved => console.log({resolved}), rejected => {console.log({rejected})})
.catch(console.error)`

Comment: Add your code, it will be more helpful to suggest an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `then`:

```js
someAsyncTask()
  .then(
    data => {
      if (!data) {
        throw new Error('Bad data') // Or, return Promise.reject(...)
      }
    },
    () => {
      // If you need logic to handle when someAsyncTask rejects
      // AND you want to continue to the next rejection handler,
      // (in this case the catch), you'll need to either `throw`
      // an error here or `return Promise.reject()`
    }
  )
  .catch(
    err => {
      // err.name === 'Error'
      // err.message === 'Bad data'
    }
  )
```

With `async/await`:

```js
(async () => {
  try {
    const data = await someAsyncTask()
    if (!data) {
      throw new Error('Bad data')
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // err.name === 'Error'
    // err.message === 'Bad data'
  }
})()
```

Comment: Note, `.catch()` will only be reached if the error is `throw`n at function set at second parameter of `.then()`

Comment: Not true -- `throw`ing even inside a resolve handler will invoke the next rejection handler (in this case, `catch`).

Comment: `new Promise(_ => {
  throw new Error(0);
}).then(console.log, console.error)
.catch(e => console.error(e, "not reached"))`

Comment: That's because `console.error` is your rejection handler, and because you're not explicitly `throw`ing again, the `then` returns a resolved Promise.  Thus, of course it would never execute the `catch` -- there was no error in your `then`.

Comment: That is what the first comment states. The error must be explicitly `throw`n, else the error will be handled, and any value `return`ed, not `throw`n, from second parameter of `.then()` will be converted to a resolved `Promise` that will reach `.then()` chained to `.catch()` `new Promise(_ => { throw new Error(0); }).then(console.log, _ => "handled") .catch(e => console.error(e, "not reached"))
.then(console.log)`. `// Handle rejection` is not `throw`

Comment: What?  I am `throw`ing and it gets caught in the `catch`...?  See https://jsbin.com/yahivazuce/edit?js,console

Comment: What is the purpose of `// Handle rejection` at the code at the first example if that is not what occurs? If `someAsyncTask()` is rejected, `throw` or `return Promise.reject()` would need to be used within second parameter of `.then()` to reach `.catch()`

Comment: That's a placeholder for whatever logic is needed if `someAsyncTask` rejects.  You're correct about having to `throw` or `return Promise.reject()` from the first rejection handler, but that's not what my example code is illustrating.